# How to set up routes in more than one place in an application. Is it possible?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 2 app that is being consumed by another app as a component library. The consumed app is using routes, and they are configured there in a designated module, and all is working fine.

The problem is that the consumer app that imports this library will need more routes in addition to the routes that are defined in the library app. So I will need to set up these routes in the consumer application. Is there a way to define routes in more than one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set up routes in any module. I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted in the APM-Final-Updated folder

I have routes in both app.module.ts and in product.module.ts. We then pull in the routes with an imports statement.

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
    ProductModule
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a concrete example. It looks like those routes all use the same router-outlet. Is that true?

Comment: These particular ones do, but they don't have to. I have an example of child router outlets and secondary (auxiliary) router outlets here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Router Class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html), you can redefine the routes on the fly

```
router.resetConfig([
  // ...
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can set up Routes in any module. This is how we set up lazy loading in Angular apps .

I order to see setting up of routes and also lazy loading you can check my repo .

https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/footballdetails

appmodule code

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,CompetitionComponent,DropdownDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    routing,
    //TableModule, Omitted for webpack lazy loading
    //TeamModule, Omitted for webpack lazy loading
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    LoadingAnimateModule.forRoot(),// temporary solution to loading
    ProgressBarModule
  ],
  providers:[CompetitionService,LoadingAnimateService ]// temporary solution to loading
})
export class AppModule {

}
```